# How do I place a logo above the title using rmarkdown when using docx output

Tags: r-markdown, officer, officedown

I'm trying to build a RMarkdown template to match a corporate template, which includes a large .png logo on the first page before the title, author and date.

With latex/pdf output we appear to be able to solve this with
`--header-includes` in the yaml, but this isn't an option for docx output.

I've seen examples where an image is inserted into the title (paying attention to whitespace after the image line):

```
author: "name"
title: |
  ![](path/to/image.png)  
  My Title
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  officedown:rdocx_document:
    reference_docx: my_template.DOCX
```

This compiles, but the resulting DOCX gives a warning of unreadable content in the document when opened. If I let Word attempt to recover, the image is replaced with a red x and a "picture can not be displayed".

The image is also included in the main body towards the end of the document.
If it is excluded from the `title:` but remains in the body, it will render fine, so it's not a problem with the image. However, if it is in the body and in the `title:` then both are replaced with "picture can not be displayed". i.e. Including it in the yaml breaks the image throughout the document.

I've also tried using a "first page different" header in the docx template (i.e. this question/answer: [Rmarkdown to Word output - insert image above header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021880/rmarkdown-to-word-output-insert-image-above-header)), however this gets inserted AFTER the Title/TOC before the first bit of body text for some reason.

Is this a bug with rmarkdown? officedown? or am I trying to do something which is impossible? Does anyone know an alternative workaround, or replicate this problem?